# Append random timestamps to a date field while subtracting days from todays date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following SQL uses `getdate()` to select today's date and appends a random timestamp:

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(SECOND ,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 86400,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112))) 
   AS DUEDATE
FROM [dbo].[Table] as t
```

producing

```
2021-02-03 21:11:21.000
2021-02-03 15:51:06.000
2021-02-03 14:08:24.000
2021-02-03 16:10:50.000
2021-02-03 02:56:00.000
```

This SQL uses `getdate()` to get todays date and subtracts the value from `t.daysago` (e,g 1,2,3,4,5 etc) to produce a date in the past (e.g., today's date - 5 days)

```
select 
(Dateadd(day, -t.daysago, Getdate()))   
FROM [dbo].[Table] as t
```

which produces these descending dates but having the same timestamps in each row.

```
2021-02-02 12:38:09.133
2021-02-01 12:38:09.133
2021-01-30 12:38:09.133
2021-01-29 12:38:09.133
2021-01-28 12:38:09.133
```

I need to vary the time stamps so the data in my demo dashboard looks realistic.

I am trying to combine the two approaches but am having trouble. I want to use `getdate()` to produce today's date, then subtract the value in `t.daysago` from todays date, and then randomize the timestamp.

If today's date and current time was 2021-02-03 22:11:31.000 I'd like to produce the following (by subtracting the values in `t.daysago` (1,2,3,4,5):

```
2021-02-02 22:11:31.000
2021-02-01 15:51:06.000
2021-01-30 14:08:24.000
2021-01-29 16:10:50.000
2021-01-28 02:56:00.000
```

I can't seem to figure out how to combine the approaches to get the desired output. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is ugly but:  select
DATEADD(SECOND ,RAND( CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 86400, CONVERT(Datetime(day, -ts.daysago, Getdate()) )
                AS DueDate
FROM [dbo].[TaskSummary] as ts

Comment: [edit] it into your question. And explain what isn't working about it.

Comment: will try. It just isn't even close to working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still use the above logic with some changes , you can choose `SECOND` or play with `number` param for DATEADD for tighter or wider range :

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(MILLISECOND ,CHECKSUM(NEWID()) ,GETDATE())    AS DUEDATE
FROM [dbo].[Table] as t
```

For example If you want to have controlled range for example for dates in 5 days range from A specific date:

you can declare @startdate whataver you want

```
DECLARE @dayrange int = 5

SELECT
   DATEADD(SECOND ,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 86400,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, - t.daysago ,GETDATE(),112))) 
   AS DUEDATE
FROM [dbo].[Table] as t
```

Comment: I need to replace that @dayrange logic with "getdate()  -t.daysago'. Trying to.

Comment: This is not quite working ```DATEADD(SECOND ,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 86400 * -t.daysago + 3,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112))) 
    AS DueDate,``` as it produces random dates it seems ```2021-01-27 19:06:01.000
2021-02-02 02:04:39.000
2021-02-02 10:53:21.000
2021-01-14 00:43:07.000
2021-01-14 10:48:51.000```

Comment: yes. I am working with that. I need to use the value in my t.daysago column and subtract that for getdate() instead of @StartDate. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I get his error: ```Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 131
Incorrect syntax near 'days'.   
``` I tried changing days to day but didn't like that either.

Comment: Dropping days may have fixed it.  Testing now. ```DATEADD(SECOND ,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 86400,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112)) -ts.daysago) ```

Comment: try now , I updated my answer again, sorry I'm just typing it in here

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. That was tricky. So nice have your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rand()` to add some random time as well like below:

```
select 
    (Dateadd(day, -t.daysago, dateadd(minute,round(rand()*rand()*25,0),Getdate())))   
FROM [dbo].[Table] as t
```

Comment: this isn't randomizing the timestamp,. Trying to figure it out as it looks close. Output is ```2021-01-17 13:25:17.327
2021-01-18 13:25:17.327
2021-01-19 13:25:17.327
2021-01-20 13:25:17.327
2021-01-21 13:25:17.327```